# GWT popup scrolling problems on Android default browser

Tags: android, gwt, popup, iscroll, mgwt

To each problem I had encountered earlier I was able to find a solution here, but this problem is really annoys me.
I have GWT application with gwt-maps library. Then you click a marker the pop up infowindow appears with a scrollpanel in it. So everything works perfect on pc browsers, iOS safary and chrome, android browsers. Only problem is on Galaxy Tab 10.1 GT-P7501 (os v3.2) default browser. I am not able to scroll that pop up window in it.
I've found the issues that this scrolling problem was on all android devices, but now it is somehow solved. I tried to use:

1. -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
2. -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

Also I've found the iScroll gwt wrapper - http://code.google.com/p/gwt-iscroll/ it did not work either, but I am not sure if I used it correctly.
So does anyone know how to solve it?

**Additional**
Found an example with scrollable pop up, which works on that Galaxy tab, but again I don't know how to intergrate it to GWT app. http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/a-look-at-iscroll-native-way-of-scrolling-content-in-mobile-webkit/
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, m-gwt made unable lo load my application with non-webkit android browsers at all.

After long search, I was managed to find src which helped me to achive pop up scrolling on android 3 default browser.

The link is http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/branches/2.1/bikeshed/src/com/google/gwt/mobile/client/?r=8145

You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mobile library for GWT ( http://www-m-gwt.com/ ) which also solves scrolling on mobile devices. You may want to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After some weird problems I was able to integrate it to me project in the way I need it. As soon as I get the answer, I'll write.